# iOS real device Unknown device or simulator UDID

Tags: appium, appium-ios, udid, appium-desktop

Appium was giving me the error

> The 'idevice_id' program is not installed. If you are running a real device test it is necessary. Install with 'brew install libimobiledevice --HEAD.

Then I followed the steps below.

```
brew uninstall ideviceinstaller
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew unlink libimobiledevice && brew link libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller
brew unlink ideviceinstaller && brew link ideviceinstaller
```

NOW I am getting this error:

> Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unknown device or simulator UDID: ‘G9F8D9FS9DFDF76159347C6GD09FDF’

When I type the

```
idevice_id --list
```

command, my UDID shows up. I do not understand why Appium would not recognize it.

I am using Appium 1.14.1 on an iPhone X with iOS version 12.4.
It is a real device.

Comment: I think that error happens because of the new UDID format for the newer devices. I believe there's a fix for it in idevice in the GitHub issues somewhere. Will search for it later

Comment: It got fixed. The issues was that the UDID letters were supposed to be small case.